# SelectAll In Datagrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I found a nice solution for SelectAll Checkboxes in a datagrid using XAML only:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TestGrid" Tag="false">
   <DataGrid.Resources> 
       <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderCheckbox">
           <CheckBox Name="SelectAll" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=Tag, Mode=TwoWay}" /> 
       </DataTemplate>    
       <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemCheckbox"> 
           <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=Tag, Mode=OneWay}" /> 
       </DataTemplate> 
   </DataGrid.Resources> 
   <DataGrid.Columns> 
       <DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderCheckbox}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ItemCheckbox}" /> 
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" /> 
   </DataGrid.Columns> 
 </DataGrid>
```

Source: [Complete XAML Solution For SelectAll In Datagrid](http://jebarson.info/post/2013/01/05/complete-xaml-solution-for-selectall-in-datagrid.aspx)

But it's my question... In above example, the **ItemCheckbox** is bound to tag property of Datagrid, then **how do I to bind the ItemCheckbox to my data field *inclusive***?

Comment: Which `CheckBox` do you want bind? In the header, against the item or both?

Comment: @dkozl I want to bind the ItemCheckbox

Comment: Are you suggesting that you want to bind both the HeaderCheckbox and ItemCheckbox to a property in your ViewModel? Or do you want to bind the ItemCheckbox to a property on your Item but want the HeaderCheckbox to toggle that value as well?

Comment: @LeeO. "I want to bind the ItemCheckbox to a property on my Item but want the HeaderCheckbox to toggle that value as well"

Comment: @ClickOk how do you populate your `DataGrid`? Is it your class, `DataTable` or something else?

Comment: @dkozl ObservableCollection of a custom class

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution I can see it to use properties in your view model instead of `Tag`. First in class that holds items create `SelectAll` property that will update accordingly all items when changed:

```
public class MyItemCollection : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<MyItem> _items;

    public ICollection<MyItem> Items { get { return _items; } }

    private bool _selectAll;

    public bool SelectAll
    {
        get { return _selectAll; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectAll != value)
            {
                _selectAll = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectAll");
                foreach (var item in _items) item.IsSelected = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then add `IsSelected` property to your item. It will be updated either by `SelectAll` property or `CheckBox` in `DataGrid`

```
public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected != value)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then update your binding to point to new properties:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TestGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderCheckbox">
         <CheckBox Name="SelectAll" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.SelectAll}" />
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemCheckbox">
         <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGrid.Resources>

</DataGrid>
```